# Backbone.js error reporting practices

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, error-logging, error-reporting

I am in the design process of a fairly robust rich client application which I tend to base the client code on Backbone, and I am curious as to the available/recommended error reporting implementation.

Due to our dependency on fat client-ish code, we want to know as much as we can about javascript error occurring.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest making your main `App` namespace object extend `Backbone.events` and listen for "error" events and report the details accordingly. This will be a nice central place to aggregate all errors and report them uniformly. You could combine various techniques for actually logging the error including displaying a notice to the user, adding some details to a hidden node in the DOM for tech support, or sending details to a remote service on the web.

Then throughout your code base you will need to actually detect/catch the errors (which usually means explicitly coding to check for them in JavaScript), gather the relevant information (perhaps a decent stack trace), and fire an "error" event into the `App` event bus. This could be errors such as DOM selectors missing that should be there when rendering a view, unexpected data received from the server, etc.

For errors with AJAX/HTTP requests, you can override `Backbone.sync` and add an additional error reporting there. That is a nice central place where all your interactions with the server will happen. Follow the same pattern of detect the error, gather details, fire an "error" event into the main `App` event bus, then either allow the application to continue if possible or degrade/fail gracefully if the error is unrecoverable.